# Ubuntu Unable to find glibc2.14

Tags: ubuntu, glibc, libc

I am trying to run a really old application that was compiled on the 2.6.24 kernel. But whenever I try to run the software I get the error-:

```
./deskewDeslant: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./deskewDeslant)
./deskewDeslant: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./deskewDeslant)
```

I have tried the following-:

```
apt-get install libc6
```

And I get the message the latest version of libc is already installed. I am currently using libc version 2.7. How do I downgrade the version to 2.14 ?

I have tried compiling version 2.14 from source from the GNU site with no luck.

**How can I downgrade my gibc to 2.14 ? Whats the proper process ?** I am running Ubuntu Hardy Heron since the program was specifically compiled on version 2.6.24.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to run a really old application that was compiled on the 2.6.24 kernel.

The kernel version is irrelevant.

Your application was compiled on a system using `GLIBC-2.14` (or newer), so it's *not that old* (`GLIBC-2.14` [was released on 2011-06-01](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Glibc%20Timeline)).

> `./deskewDeslant: /lib/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by ./deskewDeslant)`

The error above means that your current GLIBC is *too old*.

> `./deskewDeslant: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./deskewDeslant)`

The error above means that your `libstdc++.so` is also *too old*.

> I am currently using libc version 2.7. How do I downgrade the version to 2.14 ?

You believe that version `2.7` is newer than version `2.14`, but the *inverse* is true. You need to *upgrade* your `GLIBC` from `2.7` to `2.14` (or newer).

In general, a given OS distribution will never upgrade `GLIBC` from the one it originally shipped with (the risk of breaking older applications is deemed too high). This is why your `apt-get install libc6` does nothing.

Therefore, your choices are:

1. upgrade the entire distribution, or
2. obtain a binary compiled for your (old) distro, or
3. install a newer version of `GLIBC`, or
4. install a newer version of `GLIBC` in non-default location.

Option #2 is the simplest.

Option #1 may be the best (you would get security fixes, and other applications you download will work out of the box).

Option #3 is very risky: in addition to potentially breaking existing applications in subtle ways, upgrading system libc is the easiest way to render your system unbootable if you make a mistake in the update process.

Option #4 is quite involved technically. You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).